# Como pego o exception Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound lançado no Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec

To tentando fazer um test parecido com esse abaixo capturar a exception de um documento inexistente

```
expect(Produto.find('57e2bf76ce222fd11258cd4e')).to raise_error(Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound)
```

a mensagem da exception sendo passada é mostrada, entretanto, o test não passa :(

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound:
message:
  Document(s) not found for class Produto with id(s) 57e2bf76ce222fd11258cd4e.
summary:
  When calling Produto.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 57e2bf76ce222fd11258cd4e ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 57e2bf76ce222fd11258cd4e.
resolution:
  Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@api/bundler/gems/mongoid-71c29a805990/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:457:in `check_for_missing_documents!'
```

Não sei se tem algo relacionado com a última linha da mensagem

```
mongoid/criteria.rb:457:in `check_for_missing_documents!'
```

mas o que noto é que o raise_error não esta funcionando nessa situação. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que o seu código está sendo executado (e lançando uma exceção) e passado como parâmetro para o método `expect`, sem dar a chance do RSpec realizar qualquer tipo de verificação.

Você precisa utilizar um **bloco**. Dessa forma, a execução do conteúdo do bloco não será feita imediatamente, mas sim, determinada pelo método que você está chamando (nesse caso o método `expect`).

```
expect { Produto.find('57e2bf76ce222fd11258cd4e') }.to raise_error(Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound)
```

(Note a mudança do parêntese, pela chave)

Repare, que nesse caso, o método `expect` irá capturar a exceção lançada pelo seu código e então verificar se ela é a mesma definida no seu teste.

Comment: realmente, já havia corrigido mas mesmo assim muito obrigado pela explicação ;)